# VBA Word: save variable value for next call of the subroutine

Tags: vba, variables, ms-word

I am using VBA Word and I want to store a value in a subroutine of a macro for the next call of the subroutine. I tried to define my variable with *static*, but the variable is not reset by the next call of the macro. Therefore, the variable counts up. *Shared* doesn't work in VBA Word.

Is there a way to clear the variable for each call of the macro, or is there another way to store the value in a subroutine for the next call of the subroutine?

=========================================================
Perhaps this little example makes it clear. Static variables count up when you run the macro a second time. Dim variables do not count up at all because they forget their last value when leaving the subroutine. The last column is my desired result. Of course, *subr* is called here every 10th time. In my program it is not periodic and depends on other things that is not important here.

```
Sub count()
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 99
        'do something here
        If i Mod 10 = 0 Then Call subr(i)
        ' do soimething here
    Next i
End Sub
Sub subr(i)
    Dim how_often_called As Long
    Static how_often_called_static As Long
    
    how_often_called = how_often_called + 1
    how_often_called_static = how_often_called_static + 1
    Debug.Print " i="; i; " with dim="; how_often_called; " with static"; how_often_called_static    
End Sub
```

Please run count twice:

1. run of *count*:

   i= 10  with dim= 1  with static 1  wanted result = 1
   i= 20  with dim= 1  with static 2  wanted result = 2
   i= 30  with dim= 1  with static 3  wanted result = 3
   i= 40  with dim= 1  with static 4  wanted result = 4
   i= 50  with dim= 1  with static 5  wanted result = 5
   i= 60  with dim= 1  with static 6  wanted result = 6
   i= 70  with dim= 1  with static 7  wanted result = 7
   i= 80  with dim= 1  with static 8  wanted result = 8
   i= 90  with dim= 1  with static 9  wanted result = 9
2. run of *count*:

   i= 10  with dim= 1  with static 10  wanted result = 1
   i= 20  with dim= 1  with static 11  wanted result = 2
   i= 30  with dim= 1  with static 12  wanted result = 3
   i= 40  with dim= 1  with static 13  wanted result = 4
   i= 50  with dim= 1  with static 14  wanted result = 5
   i= 60  with dim= 1  with static 15  wanted result = 6
   i= 70  with dim= 1  with static 16  wanted result = 7
   i= 80  with dim= 1  with static 17  wanted result = 8
   i= 90  with dim= 1  with static 18  wanted result = 9

=============================================================
I have found two solutions:

```
Option Explicit
Dim i_global As Long
Public i_public As Long

Sub count()
    Dim i As Long
    
    i_global = 0        ' reset i_global for every call of the module
    i_public = 0        ' reset i_public for every call of the module
    For i = 1 To 99
        If i Mod 10 = 0 Then Call subr(i)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "---------------------------------------------------"

End Sub
Private Sub subr(i)
    Dim i_dim As Long
    Static i_static As Long
    
    i_global = i_global + 1
    i_dim = i_dim + 1
    i_static = i_static + 1
    i_public = i_public + 1
    Debug.Print " i="; i; " dim="; i_dim; " static"; i_static; " global"; i_global; " public"; i_public

End Sub
```

In my case, a public variable seems excessive. A global variable is sufficient. The output is:

```
 i= 10  dim= 1  static 28  global 1  public 1 
 i= 20  dim= 1  static 29  global 2  public 2 
 i= 30  dim= 1  static 30  global 3  public 3 
 i= 40  dim= 1  static 31  global 4  public 4 
 i= 50  dim= 1  static 32  global 5  public 5 
 i= 60  dim= 1  static 33  global 6  public 6 
 i= 70  dim= 1  static 34  global 7  public 7 
 i= 80  dim= 1  static 35  global 8  public 8 
 i= 90  dim= 1  static 36  global 9  public 9 
---------------------------------------------------
```

Output fo 2nd run:

```
 i= 10  dim= 1  static 37  global 1  public 1 
 i= 20  dim= 1  static 38  global 2  public 2 
 i= 30  dim= 1  static 39  global 3  public 3 
 i= 40  dim= 1  static 40  global 4  public 4 
 i= 50  dim= 1  static 41  global 5  public 5 
 i= 60  dim= 1  static 42  global 6  public 6 
 i= 70  dim= 1  static 43  global 7  public 7 
 i= 80  dim= 1  static 44  global 8  public 8 
 i= 90  dim= 1  static 45  global 9  public 9 
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How do you distinguish between the cases where you should carry the value over and the cases where it should reset?  Most likely, you should do this as a module-level variable (that's what `Static` variables turn into) with a separate sub to reset it.

Comment: Static variables live longer than a module. So if you start the module a second time, the static variable is not reset but continues to increment. I want that the variable should live for the live time of the module. If you restart the module, the variable should be reset.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "restart the module."  In my experience with VBA, there isn't any way to do that outside of the developer view of the VBA project.  Maybe we mean different things by the word "module."

Comment: What is VB Word? If you mean VBA then change your tags.

Comment: "Restart the module" means to run the macro a second time.

Comment: Static variables persist until the end of the program, not the routine, so in this context they reset only when you quit Word. If you need to reset the value you can easily do that by passing a parameter to the routine to indicate that the variable should be re-initialised.

Comment: That's right. The question is how can I reset static variables (e.g. to 0) each time the macro is called, or how do I get the output I want?